# How do I use a vlookup and If statement together, to solve a question in excel?

Tags: excel

[image]

I would like to determine whether each person is just an applicant or a bank account holder(Payer) too, for their car insurance.  I tried a vlookup, but I know that won't suffice for this problem.

Can anyone help please? I've attached the excel sheet as an image.

Answer (score 0):

1st of all, you'll need to populate the applicant and back account holder columns somehow, for a simple solution, let's say 1 or 0 for the applicant column,
2 or 0 for the Bank account holder column
Then the direct solution to your problem is something like this:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(C2,$I$2:$J$5,2,0)+VLOOKUP(C2,$I$2:$J$5,3,0)>=2,"Bank account holder","Applicant")
```

I would merge both applicant and account holder columns into one, then either put a key (1 or 2), or the role name itself (gross and simple):

```
John's mum | applicant
John       | bank account holder
```

then a simple VLOOKUP would work

```
=VLOOKUP(C2,$I$2:$J$5,2,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Vlookup won't work with the way this data is laid out, because it will always return the first result when it finds the person it wants then it will quit the job without looking any further down the columns.

A good work around is to make column E concatenate the two values together (i.e. put in column E row 2 "=C2&D2" and pull down to get a bunch of cells which look like "John's MumAccount Holder" (all contained in the one adjacent cell)

Then do a countif to see how often John's mum is an account holder in your H column

= IF(countif($E$2:$E$500,H2&$I$1)>0,"Yes, Current Applicant","No")
 and do the same for the bank account holder column.

Or you could use a nested if to combine it all into one column to see if they are either both an account holder and applicant or one of either

= IF(AND(countif($E$2:$E$500,H2&"Applicant")>0,countif($E$2:$E$500,H2&"Account Holder")>0)"Both applicant and account holder",IF(countif($E$2:$E$500,H2&"Applicant")>0,"Current Applicant",IF(countif($E$2:$E$500,H2&"Account Holder")>0,"Account Holder","Not in System")))